const Iteration over values of an array
In Rust, it is possible to iterate over values of an array:
const COOL_NUMBERS: [i32; 4] = [1, 3, 3, 7];

fn do_something_cool() {
    for number in COOL_NUMBERS {
        // ...
    }
}

But it is not possible to do in const context (at least not on stable):
const COOL_NUMBERS: [i32; 4] = [1, 3, 3, 7];

const fn do_something_cool() {
    for number in COOL_NUMBERS {
        // ...
    }
}

error[E0015]: cannot convert `[i32; 4]` into an iterator in constant functions
 --> src/lib.rs:4:19
  |
4 |     for number in COOL_NUMBERS {
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants

...

See playground link for full list of errors.
I know that it is possible to do things like this to sidestep the error:
const COOL_NUMBERS: [i32; 4] = [1, 3, 3, 7];

const fn do_something_cool() {
    do_for_loop(&COOL_NUMBERS)
}

const fn do_for_loop(numbers: &[i32]) {
    match numbers {
        [] => {}
        [number, rest @ ..] => {
            // ...
            do_for_loop(rest);
        }
    }
}

But frankly, this looks horrible, isn't there a better way?
So, my question is:

Is there a cleaner way to const-iterate over an array in stable?

Is there at least a cleaner way to const-iterate over an array in unstable?

Are there any crates that help with doing this?



Please don't include answers in the question. The right place is to add a self-answer like you did initially.

After some more searching I found out that it's possible to do this in stable:
const COOL_NUMBERS: [i32; 4] = [1, 3, 3, 7];

const fn do_something_cool() {
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < COOL_NUMBERS.len() {
        let number = COOL_NUMBERS[i];
        // ...
        i += 1;
    }
}

If you need a crate to work with const Iterators, you may use konst. Here's an example from konst docs:
use konst::iter::{ConstIntoIter, IsIteratorKind};

struct Upto10(u8);

impl ConstIntoIter for Upto10 {
    type Kind = IsIteratorKind;
    type IntoIter = Self;
    type Item = u8;
}

impl Upto10 {
    const fn next(mut self) -> Option<(u8, Self)> {
        if self.0 < 10 {
            let ret = self.0;
            self.0 += 1;
            Some((ret, self))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

const N: u32 = {
    let mut n = 0u32;
    konst::iter::for_each!{elem in Upto10(7) =>
        n = n * 10 + elem as u32;
    }
    n
};

assert_eq!(N, 789);

